How to Add Custom Headers (User-Agent, Accept) to WCF Service Using bnoffer.owncloudsharp without Modifying Method Signatures?
we are working on an ASP.NET web application that consumes a WCF service. This WCF service interacts with OwnCloud using the bnoffer.owncloudsharp library. After enabling WAF (Web Application Firewall), the WAF flags my API requests with a rule (OtherBots - ruleId 30070), indicating that valid headers like User-Agent and Accept are missing.
Problem:
we cannot modify the Client class from the bnoffer.owncloudsharp library because it is decompiled, but we need to add custom headers (like User-Agent and Accept) to every request made by this client without changing the method signatures of my existing methods. we have around 30 references in the codebase where methods like DirectoryExist, CreateDirectory, Upload, etc., are being called.
Here is the structure of the OwnCloud class I am using:
using owncloudsharp;
using owncloudsharp.Types;

public class OwnCloud
{
    private Client c;

    public OwnCloud(string owncloudURL, string userId, string password)
    {
        c = new Client(owncloudURL, userId, password);
    }

    public bool DirectoryExist(string path)
    {
        return c.Exists(path);
    }

    public bool CreateDirectory(string path)
    {
        return c.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    public bool Upload(string path, Stream data, string contentType)
    {
        return c.Upload(path, data, contentType);
    }
    
    // ... other methods
}


Client Constructor (decompiled, not modifiable):
public Client(string url, string user_id, string password)
{
    if (url != null && url.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        url = url.TrimEnd('/');
    }

    this.url = url;
    rest = new RestClient();
    rest.BaseUrl = new Uri(url + "/ocs/v1.php/");
    rest.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(user_id, password);
    rest.AddDefaultParameter("format", "xml");
    dav = new WebDavManager();
    dav.Credential = new WebDavCredential(user_id, password);
    dav.Credential.AuthenticationType = AuthType.Basic;
}


My Goal:
Add the custom headers (User-Agent: app/1.0, Accept: application/json) to every request made by the Client class without modifying the method signatures of my existing OwnCloud class or the decompiled Client class.
Attempts:
we are  considering wrapping the Client class to add the headers, but we want to know if there’s a better way to centralize the header management without modifying existing signatures.
Any advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated!

I think the most effective way to do this would be to integrate your current client and make a custom client to add header information without being modified.
